# How to use bootable usb on an ubuntu machine

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, usb

Let me clarify.  My machine had Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. Well it crashed and now I'm burning the 32-bit version (yes I'm sure my machine is 32-bit) of 13.04 iso onto my flash drive, using a windows vista computer.

When I plug in my drive into my ubuntu computer and hit the power button, what do I do? Is there a secret key I need to push on boot-up for the option to boot from a usb drive?

Thanks, S

Comment: To know if there is a "secret key" we need to at least know about your PC model. You need to access the BIOS setup, but different manufacturer give different ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a secret key I need to push on boot-up for the option to boot from a usb drive?

I don't know much about your particular computer, but if I had to guess, I'd say *probably*. Realistically, it depends on your computer's make and model.

You should pay close attention to your [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) splash screen when you start the computer up, and look for something like `Press (button) to select boot device`. If this cannot be found, look for a button to to enter into your BIOS settings, and change the order of boot devices, prioritizing your flash drive.

Please note that some computer (especially older ones) cannot boot from USB. However, if you go to your manufacture's website, you may find a BIOS update that adds this function. If a newer BIOS cannot be found, assuming you can get your BIOS to boot from a "smart" boot manager, such as [PLOP](http://www.plop.at/en/home.html), you may be able to force your computer to boot from USB anyway, even though you BIOS doesn't support it.

I should note if you push the pause button on your keyboard (usually located above the number pad on the right), your BIOS will freeze it self until you press a button on your keyboard (any button). This will probably make it easier to read what's on your screen.

PS: your computer's manual is your friend! It can probably give a much more specific example as to how you boot from different devices than anyone here can.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either set your computer to boot from usb first in your bios options, or you can use your boot list to boot to usb first just this time. The key to enter these varies by system. For me F2 enters bios settings, or I can use F11 to enter boot menu for a 1 time usb boot. I would suggest you try pressing F11 first, as it's a commonly used one for bios boot menus.